# Durable Nonce Signer Requirements

Tags: durable-nonce

Is the nonce authority of a durable nonce a required signer when the nonce is used for the transaction blockhash?

Is that account required to be the only signer?

Answer (score 2):

> Is the nonce authority of a durable nonce a required signer when the nonce is used for the transaction blockhash?

Yes. The nonce authority must sign the transaction in order to advance the nonce, which is a requirement when using a nonce.

> Is that account required to be the only signer?

No, the transaction can have any number of signers, same as any normal transaction!

You've likely already seen them, but more docs on nonces at https://docs.solana.com/offline-signing/durable-nonce

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Jon - From what I've read, the nonce account seems to be on-curve with a corresponding private key, is that right? It has a nonce-authority, that has the ability to advance the nonce & sign transactions using it.

So, does ownership of the nonce account's private key matter? Or have I misunderstood what is happening? I would have expected the nonce account to be an off-curve PDA.